# PHP: Syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a backend REST API using php Laravel, but I encountered the strange error from my title in the following code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main');
});

 Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
            // Authentication Routes
            Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
            Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
            Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@store');
            Route::post('/register/student', 'Auth\RegisterStudentController@store');


            // Model routes
            Route::resource('/internships', 'InternshipController');
            Route::resource('/companies', 'CompanyController');
            Route::resource('/students', 'StudentController');
        });
```

At the following line:

```
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@store');
```

I'm getting this error:

> Syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)

The problem is that I don't have any  `<<` in this line. I tried to delete the line, but the error moves just before `});`, on the last `;`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try clearing your cache php artisan cache:clear

Comment: it could be the use of namespaces inside a named callback, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I was facing the same problem due to SVN conflict there was code like this >>>>>>> .r6 in so many files I removed that from all files and issues resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`T_SL` references to `<<`.

You should not use tabs or spaces before you use `END;`